# Man-in-the-middle SSL generation on request possible

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

I am doing some research on man-in-the-middle focusing on SSL  in particular.

I have been looking into  generating a certificate on request when a client connects and requests a secured page.

Assuming that;

- Client is connected to AP controlled by me and ignoring cert validation
- AP is running airmon-ng and airbas-ng with DHCP.
- OS is Debian on a Rasp Pi, that then forwards to the real WWW

Is it feasible to generate a certificate per request, and if so, are tools available for this, or would the request have to be scripted to sign a cert via OpenSSL, and logging the event.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I use [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) (and [HoneyProxy](http://honeyproxy.org/) a graphical interface to it) at work to do that. Works perfectly.

Relevant part of the documentation about SSL:
http://mitmproxy.org/doc/ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

10 seconds of [googling](https://www.google.ch/search?q=X509%20cert%20generation%20on%20the%20fly) gives you a link to the [dynamic SSl generation feature of Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DynamicSslCert) and that links to the (necessary) [SSLBump feature](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump) that implements the MITM attack itself.